# how to fill both thumbs up and thumbs down of glyphicon, which css style should have to use?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

here I'm using glyphicon not other icons (fa icons), I'm able to color the icon but that is not completely filled color in the icon as like Facebook like

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="${botId}-like-dislike-ctl">
    <button class="btn" style="color:blue;" id="red"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button class="btn" style="" id="green"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. these icons cannot be changes like font awesome icons by font weight. please refer this link to see the options they provide https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_thumbs-up&stacked=h

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52422041/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own ttf font with symbols, i.a. filled thumbs up at https://fontello.com/

You can also upload your own image / icon as svg and paste in the font.

Can it be helpful?

Example added 25. feb:

https://luren.no/icon-font-example/font.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I guess this should explain simple
https://luren.no/icon-font-example/font.html
k

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31152641)